# Can I use "rather than" after semicolon?

Tags: prepositions

Can I use "rather than" after a semicolon?
For example:

> He had planned to cook 3 pizzas. Eventually, he cooked 5 pizzas: Margherita, Marinara, Prosciutto e funghi, Quattro Stagioni and Quattro Formaggi; rather than just 3.

Comment: You can, depending on the effect you want, but see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62681/using-a-comma-before-rather-than) which suggests either a comma or no punctuation before "rather than".

Comment: This would be non-standard. As [Margherita, Marinara, Prosciutto e funghi, Quattro Stagioni and Quattro Formaggi] is essentially a parenthetical (a 'spelling-out' appositive in this case), it should be set off as such. Zero punctuation would be wrong in this example, and commas confusing on top of the listing commas. A pair of brackets or dashes is correct.

Comment: *Pace* @StuartF, I’d point out that in this example,  the colon introduces an enumeration, and the follow-on thought feels abruptly incongruous. Better to replace the :-; pair by dashes or parentheses to clearly bound the list of pizza types.

Comment: Would this sound natural and correct then?
He had planned to cook three pizzas. Eventually, he cooked five pizzas -Margherita, Marinara, Prosciutto e funghi, Quattro Stagioni and Quattro Formaggi-, rather than just three.

Comment: Just use a comma.

Comment: What I suggested is “Eventually, he cooked 5 pizzas—margherita, marinara, prosciutto e funghi, quattro stagioni and quattro formaggi—rather than just 3.”

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use "rather than" after a semi-colon if the clause it introduces is syntactically dependent on a *preceding* clause; but if the clause introduced by "rather than" is dependent on a *subsequent* clause, it can follow a semicolon:

> He took the train; rather than taking a car. <sup>wrong</sup>
>
> He took the train; rather than have his brother meet him when he arrived, he planned to take a taxi. <sup>OK</sup>